# jQuery accordion is slightly glitchy could be smoother

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

So I am using a jQuery accordion for a job interview project and really want it to be smooth so I it looks good.

http://cpkdesign.com/uiaustin

It is on the left hand side. There are a few other things too. When you click a link there is an awkward blue selection box that appears, also I would like to turn on the small triangle images so they aren't strangely placed like they are now.

Comment: The community shouldn't be helping you out for a job interview.

Comment: So, if I fix it for you, do I get the job instead of you?

Comment: looking back on this now, I was a total noob. Thanks for bearing with me and helping out to those who did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> really want it to be smooth so it looks good

You really need to define this more, but I presume you are talking about how the contents of the accordion jump when it is opened.

This seems to be due to the default margin that is applied to the s. Setting margin: 0; on these fixes the problem. Better yet, use a css reset. [This](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) one is widely used.

> When you click a link there is an awkward blue selection box that appears

You can use outline on the  elements to remove this.

```
outline: 0;
```

See http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/ for more help.

> I would like to turn on the small triangle images so they aren't strangely placed like they are now

As for the arrows, you can apply the following css in order to position them:

```
.arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: James. I really appreciate the advice. And yes, that is exactly what I meant. Next time I will try to be more concise with my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Change your css, you co do something like this:

```
#accordionarea a {
    outline: none;
}

.arrow-down {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Maybe a bit strange we have to do this for you?

Comment: I wasn't asking for you to do it for me, just a point in the right direction. I appreciate you helping though.

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer. It was a dumb question.